# list comprehension without parentheses in a function

Tags: coffeescript

I have a function that needs to return the last property of an object that satisfies the condition:

```
types = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}

g = (s) -> v for k, v of types when k is s

console.log g 'b'
```

this code prints `[ 2 ]`

I expected just `2`, and not an array. And indeed, this code does print what I expect:

```
console.log v for k, v of types when k is 'b'
```

What is wrong?

P.S. I know that instead of this function I can just access the object's property using `[]`, but this is a contrived example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we rearrange the code then things should be clearer.

Your second piece of code:

```
console.log v for k, v of types when k is 'b'
```

is just another way of writing this:

```
for k, v of types when k is 'b'
  console.log(v)
```

or even:

```
for k, v of types
  if k is 'b'
    console.log(v)
```

Since there is only one `'b'` key, only one `console.log` call is made.

Your first piece of code:

```
g = (s) -> v for k, v of types when k is s
```

is the same as this:

```
g = (s) ->
  a = (v for k, v of types when k is s)
  a
```

The loop, `v for k, v of types when k is s` yields an array by definition so `a` will be an array (with only one element) and `g` will return an array.

Answer (score 1):

`console.log v for k, v of types when k is 'b'` will call `console.log(v)` for every `v` when `k` satisfies the condition whereas your first code snipped will call `console.log(g(b))`. If there were two elements in `types` that satisfied the condition, the outputs would be:

```
[1, 2]
```

and

```
1
2
```

To make `g` output the first element that satisfies the condition, you could use `return` with early out or just take the first element of the results array.

`g = (s) -> return v for k, v of types when k is s`